# What is a noun for the level of how anthropomorphic an object is?

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider a set of objects like the following:

- a cube
- a 3-fingered robot claw
- a robot hand in the general shape of a human hand
- a human hand

Objects further down the list have more "human" characteristics, and are thus more "anthropomorphic". The list is in order of increasing "anthropomorphicity" [a fake word].

What real word could replace the fake word "anthropomorphicity"?

Comment: It's simply ***more*** *anthropomorphic*.

Comment: I seriously doubt that you can measure levels of anthropomorphism. It is not a linear concept.

Comment: There isn't one. You have to construct a scoring system, and then you have a morphometric scale.

Comment: This paper uses "anthropomorphization" for the process, but claims it is all-or-nothing, not a matter of degree https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2018.02136/full

Comment: Measure it by taking its anthropomorphature...

Answer (score -2):

I think you are looking for ***[anthropomorphism:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/anthropomorphism)***

> the showing or treating of animals, gods, and objects as if they are human in appearance, character, or behaviour.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: No,  OP is looking for a word describing a level or measure of ...  For example if something is toxic it can be so to varying degrees and this is described as *toxicity*   OP wants something like anthropomorphicity

Comment: @Jim a gradeable adjective.

Comment: This answer seems reasonable to me. We could talk about levels of anthropomorphism.  I'm not sure how useful such a scale would be. How can you measure anthropomorphism levels?

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica Using long established morphometric techniques. We've been doing this in a formal setting for 100 years or so. [Morphometrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_morphometrics_in_anthropology)

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica - Why does it matter how useful it is? OP is clearly looking for a single word that they will find useful for something.  Given there isn't a single word, "level of anthropomorphism" or "anthropomorphic level" are reasonable alternatives, but this answer doesn't say that, it just offers "anthropomorphism" on its own, which doesn't work.

Comment: @Phil Sweet - Interesting. So what is your suggested answer based on that?